# Is there any security flaw in using iframe as a communication layer cross site?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, cross-domain

### Goal of this poc:

- a way to keep the user logged in across webapps
- on different domains
- do it once, import it everywhere

### The poc:

So I thought of this possible solution. I call it the user widget.

Let's say we have service AUTH that provides the endpoint to login and logout, it also sets the `httpOnly` cookie.

This should be the header, distributed across webapps. The header downloads the iframe and with `postMessage` send calls to it, to understand if the user is already logged in, otherwise shows login:

```
<script>
    /**
     ****************************************
     * Code that should be inside the header
     ****************************************
     */
    window.onload = function() {
      (function(){
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
        } else {
            window.attachEvent("onmessage", handleMessage);
        }

        //- This could be * meaning no preferences, or a URI,
        //- but SHOULD not be * but the correct origin
        var iframeOrigin = "*";
        var iframeId = 'IFRAME-PROXY';

        createIframe(checkStatusOfLogin);

        var doLoginButton = document.getElementById('do-login');
        doLoginButton.onclick = doLogin;

        function createIframe(onLoadCallback) {
          var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
          iframe.id = iframeId;
          iframe.style.display = 'none';
          iframe.src = 'https://mysecureiframe.securedomain.com/file.html';
          document.body.appendChild(iframe);
          iframe.onload = function () {
            onLoadCallback(iframe);
          };
        }

        function checkStatusOfLogin(iframe) {
          var iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow;
          var payload = {
              action: 'status'
          };
          iframeWin.postMessage(JSON.stringify(payload), iframeOrigin);
        }

        function doLogin() {
            var iframeWin = document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow;
            var payload = {
                action: 'login',
                username: document.getElementById('username').value,
                password: document.getElementById('password').value
            };
            iframeWin.postMessage(JSON.stringify(payload), iframeOrigin);
        }

        function handleMessage(evt) {
            console.log('Inside client tab, received: ', evt);
            var userContainer = document.getElementById('user-container');
            try {
              var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(evt.data);
              if (parsedResponse.isCIA) { // checking it's a postmessage from us and not an extension
                if (parsedResponse.status == "LOGGED_IN") {
                    userContainer.classList.remove('not-logged-in');
                } else if (parsedResponse.status == 'NEED_LOGIN') {
                    userContainer.classList.add('not-logged-in');
                }
              } else {
                throw new Error('not CIA message');
              }
            } catch (e) {
              console.log('not CIA message');
            }
        }
      }());
    };
    /**
     *******************
     * End of header code
     * *****************
     */
</script>
```

The iframe contains a really simple body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://mysecureiframe.securedomain.com/loginProvider.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>IFRAME NON VISIBILE</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the content of `loginProvider.js`:

```
(function() {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent("onmessage", handleMessage);
    }

    // to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options
    // Guardare HEADER Content-Security-Policy instead of X FRame Options
    function checkStatus(success, failure) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://mysecureiframe.securedomain.com/status"; // AUTH endpoint
        http.open("GET", url, true);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
            if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                if (http.responseText == "true") {
                    success();
                } else {
                    failure();
                }
            }
        };
        http.send();
    }

    function doLoginIframe(user, pass) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://mysecureiframe.securedomain.com/login"; // AUTH endpoint
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
            if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
              if (user == 'username' && pass == 'password') {
                var payload = getPayload();
                payload.status = 'LOGGED_IN';
                parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(payload), "http://targetOrigin");
                alert(http.responseText);
              }
            }
        };
        http.send();
    }

    function getPayload() {
        return {
            isCIA: true
        };
    }

    function handleMessage(evt) {
        console.log('Inside iframe, got: ', evt); // TODO Check targetOrigin is from trusted sites
        var parsedRequest = JSON.parse(evt.data);
        if (parsedRequest.action == "status") {
            checkStatus(function() {
                var payload = getPayload();
                payload.status = 'LOGGED_IN';
                parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(payload), "http://targetOrigin");
            },
              function () {
                var payload = getPayload();
                payload.status = 'NEED_LOGIN';
                parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(payload), "http://targetOrigin");
            });
        } else if (parsedRequest.action == "login") {
            doLoginIframe(parsedRequest.username, parsedRequest.password);
        }
    }
}());
```

Besides adding the check to see if origin is a trusted site, do you see particular security flows with this strategy?

Comment: Do you check the authentication on client side? Do you ship the password in client side code?

Comment: @lupz what do you mean by "do you check the authentication on client side?" The password is given by the user, he fills a form.

Comment: Yeah. Whre do you check that the credentials are valid? If you do it on client side, an attacker could just view the source, read the password, or skip the auth check.

Comment: @lupz we call a backend endpoint, namely on the code `/login`.

Comment: Yeah. I'm just wondering about the `if (user == 'username' && pass == 'password') {...}` in the `onreadystatechange` callback.

Comment: @lupz oh thanks! No it's there only for demo purpose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134186/discussion-between-lupz-and-dierre).